# how can i connect to my postgres dpcker container via local springboot?

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, docker-compose

I am able connect to the database through PgAdmin4 with no problem with the credential specified in the docker compose file, but I cannot connect my spring boot app, nor through the terminal.

Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/customer
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
server.error.include-message=always
server.port=8082
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:alpine3.17
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: xxxx78@gmail.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: password
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
      - ./data/pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
```

I have tried watching a lot of videos on youtube,I had even tried the yml format instead of the proprieties file but no luck

I get this error when try to launch springboot

[image]

I get this one when launching the terminal
[image]

Comment: Read the error... The username/password combination is wrong.

Comment: You are using db name "customer" but default name is "postgres" (default schema is "public"). Try to change url to spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres

Comment: Compare your connection settings in pgadmin and spring application properties. I think that pgadmin using "postgres" db, and not "customer".

Comment: @Slongtong
I specified the user to be "root" and the password to be "password" in the docker compose.yml file, indeed, when I log in for the first time on pgAdmin I successfully connect to the database with no problem with the specifications mentioned above, however, there is no "postgres" user, nor any other except "root" and the database "customer" is already created because the docker-compose.yml file as it as a specification.
I have tried all your solutions and nothing worked for me.
Thanks for trying to help.
You can run the above docker-compose.yml and use the terminal to connect

Comment: I've checked your config. 
1) 2 databases created : postgres and root  (not customer db, you should provide it via env parameter POSTGRES_DB to override defaults)
2) user is "root" and password is "password"
3) from pgadmin container you can connect to postgres via dns name "postgres" (like name of service in compose file) - 
  a) host name/address - postgres (not localhost, because it's different hosts)
  b) port - 5432
  c) maintenance database - postgres or root
  d) username - root
  e) password - password

Comment: AND for localhost (java application started locally) - a) spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/root b) spring.datasource.username=root c) spring.datasource.password=password

Comment: Thanks, @Slongtong, I have done it as you have suggested it, by adding the database in the docker-compose.yml, but I am still getting the same error, I am not able to connect via the terminal, nor with spring-boot, but I am connecting without any issue with pgAdmin and the database get created indeed

Comment: If you share sources, i'll fix them with answer. (Need in more details, idk what you are doing wrong)

Comment: Thanks @Slongtong for everything; if you can run the docker-compose thing above by adding the database line,  and connect to it via the terminal, then my problem will be called solved

Answer (score 0):

Create project by screenshots and check that it works.

1. Docker-compose (with 1 difference, POSTGRES_DB env)

[image: docker-compose.yaml]

2. PG-admin: Register Server[image: server in docker]
3. PG-admin: check data[image: pg-admin]
4. Simple entity with id

[image: entity]

5. Main + insert entity with id = 1

[image]

6. application.properties

[image]

7. project structure: 4 files (except maven or gradle)

[image: structure]